# AChartEnging XYMultipleSeriesRenderer y-label padding

Tags: android, achartengine

When I use custom labels on the y-axis (actually 2 y-axises) in an AChartEngine chart, the padding setting has no effect. How do I fix this? I use the `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` and set the labels using `addYTextLabel(double y, java.lang.String text, int scale)`. The padding is set using `setYLabelsPadding`.

Please see below, the labels in the series [0, 100000, 200000] are added automatically and has padding, the rest are added manually and do not have any padding.

[image: Padding problem]

I am using version 1.1.0 of AChartEngine on Android 4.3.

Thanks
Markus

Comment: are you using AChartEngine recent 1.1.0 version....

Comment: Yes, I am using 1.1.0.

Comment: hmm k..sorry to ask can you show image as what you need..

Comment: Question updated with an image.

Answer (score 1):

Have You done this below line in `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`..

```
renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
```

then you add

```
renderer.setYLabelsPadding(10);
```

Comment: Yes, and the alignment works fine, it's the padding setting that is ignored.